# Failed to start Flipper. Error: FlipperServerConfig has not been set

Tags: android, facebook, debugging, flipper

I was using version 0.228.0 and it was working fine.
I got the notification that there's a new version 0.229.0.
Downloaded and installed it in macOS Sonoma and I got the below error.

> Failed to start Flipper. Error: FlipperServerConfig has not been set

Any idea to fix this? old version (0.228.0) is still working fine